# (php) fsockopen error, but telnet connection works

Tags: php, email, smtp, telnet, fsockopen

I'm very confused, I'm trying to send e-mails trough PHP, but I have problems with a particular mail server, with another all works fine.

When I trying:

```
$smtp_conn = fsockopen('mail.onedomain.com',25,$errno,$errstr,30);
echo $errno . '<br>' . $errstr;
```

I get:

```
110
Connection timed out
```

but...

I go to Start>cmd, and write:

```
telnet mail.onedomain.com 25
```

And I get:

```
220 server1.onedomain.local Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service Ready at Sat, 21 Jan 2012 00:05:04 +0100
```

I dont understand this, the connection is doing with telnet but I cant do it in PHP with the same params... someone has any idea?

I suspect the problem is a bad configuration of mailserver, but... how can I demostrate?

Thanks!
Carles.

Comment: Apart from the error your are receiving with this method. Have you considered using the "mail" php function? It feels like you are trying something slightly convoluted.

Comment: Both manually writing the SMTP commands to a socket and using PHP `mail` are objectively worse than using a high-quality third-party mailing library like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Shame this never got answered. I was banging my head against a brick wall with exactly the same issue. Bash `telnet` worked fine, but php `fscokopen` just failed.

Solution:  -  Use ip instead of server instead of the CNAME.

So instead of:

```
$smtp_conn = fsockopen('mail.onedomain.com',25,$errno,$errstr,30);
echo $errno . '<br>' . $errstr;
```

Use:

```
$smtp_conn = fsockopen('000.000.000.000',25,$errno,$errstr,30);
echo $errno . '<br>' . $errstr;
```